# component not rendering on update in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-component

I am creating a react application using firebase. I am updating this documents data in firestore.
Date is updating but don't know why the component is not rendering.
I have tried to update document in firestore then state is updating but data is not rendered.

This is firestores access in app.js file

```
async componentDidMount() {
    new Repository()
     .getCollectionSnapshot("users")
    .then((collectionRefData)=>{
    collectionRefData.colRef.onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
      this.setState({
        usersList:snapshot.docs
      })
     })
   })
 }
```

And this is Cards components class

```js
export class Cards extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: props.id,
      user: props.user.data(),
      active: props.user.data().is_active,
      paid: {
        is_active: true,
      },
      unpaid: {
        is_active: false,
      },
    };

    this.activateUser = this.activateUser.bind(this);
    this.deactivateUser = this.deactivateUser.bind(this);
  }

  activateUser() {
    new Repository()
      .updateData('users', this.state.id, this.state.paid)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ active: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  deactivateUser() {
    new Repository()
      .updateData('users', this.state.id, this.state.unpaid)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ active: false });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { user, active } = this.state;

    return (
      <Col>
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <b>
              <AccountCircle /> {user.displayName}
            </b>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body pt-0">
            <AlternateEmail />: {user.email}
            <div className="col-5 text-center">
              <Image image={user.profilePicture} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card-footer">
            <ButtonGroup>
              <Button>Profile</Button>
              {user.is_active && (
                <Button variant="warning" onClick={this.deactivateUser}>
                  Disable
                </Button>
              )}
              {!user.is_active && (
                <Button variant="success" onClick={this.activateUser}>
                  Enable
                </Button>
              )}
            </ButtonGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the first snippet

```
export default class User extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    usersList: null,
  };
}

async componentDidMount() {
  new Repository()
   .getCollectionSnapshot("users")
   .then((collectionRefData)=>{
   collectionRefData.colRef.onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
     this.setState({
       usersList:snapshot.docs
     })
   })
  })
 }

 render() {
  if(this.state.usersList!==null){
   return (
    <div className="App-header">
    <Header text="Users" location="Cable360/ Users" />
    <div className="card-list mt-2">
      {this.state.usersList.map((usr) => {
        return <Cards key={usr.id} id={usr.id} user={usr} />;
      })}
     </div>
    </div>
   );
  }
  return(
      <div/>
    )
 }
}
```

And this is firestores connection

```
 async getCollectionSnapshot(path) {
   return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
     const collectionRef = firestore.collection(path);
     collectionRef.get().then((data) => {
     resolve(new FirestoreProviderReply(false, data, "SUCCESS", null, collectionRef));
     }).catch((error) => {
        reject(new FirestoreProviderReply(false, error, "ERROR_OCCURED", null, collectionRef));
     });
    });
  }
```

Comment: If you put `console.log(snapshot)` inside `collectionRefData.colRef.onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{` callback, is it fire? Does it show the right data?

Comment: Yes its showing right data

Comment: Can you show the code of the `Card`s list component (of the first snippet)? Maybe React somehow doesn't re-render the `Card`s list again

Comment: yeah sure i have added it to question

Comment: I cant say I see any errors.Do you still have this issue? A few questions:
Have you attempted or considered using arrow functions in class properties?
have you seen if there is a re-render using `forceUpdate()` just to check if this is a method not running properly?